# Tricky counting formula

Tags: excel, count, vba

My data looks like this

```
1|1|1|1 101
1|1|1|2 101
1|1|1|3 101
1|1|2|1 102
1|1|2|2 102
1|1|3|1 103
1|1|3|2 103
1|1|3|3 103
1|1|3|4 103
1|1|3|5 103
1|1|4|1 104
1|1|4|2 104
1|1|4|3 104  <--- my eq works till here
1|2|1|1 105  <--- my eq needs to return 105 but all my eq modifications have failed
1|2|1|2 105
1|2|2|1 106
1|2|3|1 107
2|1|1|1 201  <--- my eq figures this switch out without issue
2|1|1|2 201
2|1|2|1 202
2|2|1|1 203  <--- my eq fails here
2|2|1|2 203
2|2|1|3 203
2|2|2|1 204
2|2|2|2 204
```

I'm trying to find a formula or a macro anything that will result in the column on the far right (101, 102, 103, etc). My current formula take Col 1 and Col 3 and combines them. The challenge is that when Col 1  is the same but the 2nd column switches I need to keep counting up.

I have tried finds, index(match,match), search, max above. I can't find the right combinations of (Excel functions, haven't tried a macro yet since I'm not quite sure how to get what I want) function to make this work please help. If extra columns are needed that's find I just can't change the first four columns.

Comment: **What formulas have you tried??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following data layout:

[image]

You can use following formula in `E2`and drag down:

```
=100*A2+IF(A2<>A1,1,MOD(E1,100)+(C2<>C1))
```

If you don't have column headers, use your formula in `E1`.

Answer (score 0):

Put your data in columns A, B, C, D. 
Put number "101" in cell E1. 
Put this formula in cell E2: =IF(AND(A2=A1;C2<>C1);E1+1;E1) and drag it down.